# Flutter InheritedWidget y deprecado inheritFromWidgetOfExactType

Tags: flutter

estoy teniendo problemas con el InheritedWidget, tenia este código de ejemplo:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:formvalidation/src/blocs/login_bloc.dart';
export 'package:formvalidation/src/blocs/login_bloc.dart';

class Provider extends InheritedWidget {
   final loginBloc = LoginBloc();
   Provider({Key key, Widget child}) : super(key: key, child: child);
   @override
   bool updateShouldNotify(InheritedWidget oldWidget) => true;
   static LoginBloc of (BuildContext context) {
     return (context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(Provider) as Provider).loginBloc;
   }
}
```

Pero ya no puedo hacer el inheritFromWidgetOfExactType, estoy intentando cambiar el código por la nueva función dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType pero no se bien como, alguna ayda? Muchas Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo tenía el mismo problema. La documentación esta un poco desactualizada.

Cambia la función `of`

```
static Provider of(BuildContext context) {
    return context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<Provider>();
  }
```

Te regresará un `Provider` pero con eso accedes a `loginBloc`.

Comment: Muchas gracias! te agradezco, justo había llegado a la misma conclusión pero intentaba acceder al loginBloc desde el Provider, y la solución es acceder desde afuera. Mil Gracias!

Comment: @Darío si te sirvió acepta la respuesta como correcta.